# how to run commands (print $_siginfo, x/i $pc) in gdb batch mode?

Tags: shell, gdb

I want to execute siginfo and $eip in batch mode. How can I do that. 
I have a core dump and symbol path and I want to execute it under shell script.
I have tried gdb -ex, but is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` characters as `\$`, or use `''` quotes instead of `""`. Otherwise, `$eip` is expanded by the shell, typically resulting in the empty string.